# how to make top left sharp corner in whatsapp chat message bubble in react native

Tags: user-interface, react-native, whatsapp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZPGp.jpg)

In above image of whatsapp chat.
How to make top left corner in react native style sheet . in web we make with "before" pseudo class but in react native stylesheet . pseudo class is not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom triangular shaped view and place it at the top left corner of bubble. Also keep the border radius of top left corner of bubble 0 so that the triangular view blends in perfectly.

You can refer the below link for creating the custom triangular shaped view.

https://reactnativecode.com/triangle-shape-view/

Comment: @MuhammadYasir can you please mark my answer correct if it was helpful to you